# how to preventDefault inside switch e.which

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why `preventDefault()` on `case 3` doesn't work? Browser's menu should not appear on right click.

```js
$('#btnB').on('mousedown', function(e){
 switch (e.which) {
 case 1:
  console.log('left');
  break;
 case 3:
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('right');
  break;
 default:
  alert('323');
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btnB'>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: How do you know that it isn't working? Perhaps you should post your code so that we can test it, as I can't see any problem with the example you've shown here.

Comment: @MartinParkin, problem is because browser's context menu appears. I posted the code, what's the problem with you?

Comment: @Ben I believe it's not really a duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as answer of @dfsq, but with catch of double trigger on contextmenu. I cannot edit his answer for some reason and I want to show a demo.

```js
$('#btnB').on('contextmenu mousedown', function(e) {
  switch (e.which) {
    case 1:
      console.log('left');
      break;
    case 3:
      if (e.type !== 'contextmenu') break;
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('right');
      break;
    default:
      alert('323');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="btnB">HAHAHA</span>
```

Comment: thanks, it works. Strange - `dfsq's` answer is incorrect and upvoted twice.

Comment: @qadenza it is *correct* and the answer here is just an improved version of it. main idea here is listening for `oncontextmenu` event ;)

Answer (score 2):

Context menu appears because it reacts to different event, not mousedown. Try to listen both `mousedown` (probably not needed even) and [`contextmenu`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oncontextmenu) events:

```js
 $('#btnB').on('mousedown contextmenu', function(e){
  switch (e.which) {
  case 1:
    console.log('left');
    break;
  case 3:
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('right');
    break;
  default:
    alert('323');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btnB'>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: Problem here is that the `right` is called twice on `mousedown` and `contextmenu`.

Comment: @qadenza That's why I said, that you probably don't even need `mousedown` event.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent the context menu from opening you can do so by listening to the contextmenu event

```
$('#btnB').on('contextmenu', function(e) {
            alert("hey new menu"); 
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```